# Get CurrentEmail Details on Outlook Addins Using NetOffice

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, netoffice

Good day, 
         Its my first time creating an addin and I have created an addin for outlook using netoffice developer toolbox, the button was created when i opened the message like the below image
[image]

but i dont know how to get the the emails information(sender) and the email itself so i can use it as an attachment. I have tried to show messagebox by using this code.

```
 public void SendButton_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Test Description", "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);         
    }
```

any idea on how to get these email info and the email itself ?

Thanks,
Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

The IRibbonControl interface provides the [Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.core.iribboncontrol.context.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property which returns an object representing the active window containing the Ribbon user interface that triggers a callback procedure. So, you may cast it to the Inspector class from the Outlook object model and use the [Inspector.CurrentItem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869722(v=office.15).aspx) property for getting an instance of the MailItem class displayed.

Comment: Hello sir, i tried using the MailItem.Body and i can get the mail body but when i use MailItem.Sender.Address it doesnt seem to do anything, note that im using NetOffice plugin